# Invoke lambda function / sending email after some logic in React Amplify

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amazon-ses

I am working on E commerce site using Amplify React JS I am looking for a way to send Mail as soon as user makes an order.
Is there any easy way using Amplify for this job I found some documents where it says I have to create lambda function I create one but would find the way to trigger or invoke that lambda

```
const data = await API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(createOrder, {
          input: {
            date: Date.now(),
            status: 'Pending',
            firstName,
            lastName,
            country,
            street,
            town,
            phone,
            email,
            note,
            total: parseInt(total),
            cartList,
          },
        })
      );
      props.refreshStore();
       /**************Send Email USING SES *******************/
        /********************* OR ******************/
        /********** Invoke Lamda function ****************/ 
      const path = '/pages/thank-you';
      history.push(path);
        
      alert('Order Has been made');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I dont know complete project layout, I guess a good start point might be to enable streams ( triggers) on `Order` table you have already created using amplify. There are plenty of [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html) and [tutorials](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) to get that working. You can get in-depth details, on stream event structure [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/)